# Exeute Batch File on a Remote Computer htrough VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a batch file in a remote machine. I also have a vb.net application in some other machine. Now all i need is to execute the batch file of that remote machine from this vb.net application.

One thing you must know is that the batch file cannot be executed unless and untill i log in to that remote machine and execute it.So all these while everytime I needed to run the batch file, I had to log in to that remote machine and then execute it.

Now I want the same through the VB.net application.Is it possible?

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread will give you a way of remotely starting a process via WMI:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/74da6635-53d1-42e0-a48e-acc36d536d28/.